# Different website URL appears from Google Search

Tags: http, redirect, seo

We have a meteor application (http://evnta.com). However, when we search our site in Google search (keyword: Global Marketplace for Event Suppliers), it shows a different URL(www.issnip2015.org instead of evnta.com). I'm not sure where 'issnip2015.org' came from.

Can you enlighten us on this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be concerned as to whether there is any crawable content for Google on either of the domains.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have two DNS pointing at the same ip address, which means both domain names "are pointing to the same website"...

```
foo@foo:~$ host evnta.com
evnta.com has address 128.199.185.5
foo@foo:~$ host issnip2015.org
issnip2015.org has address 128.199.185.5
issnip2015.org mail is handled by 0 smtp.secureserver.net.
issnip2015.org mail is handled by 10 mailstore1.secureserver.net.
```

Solution (you need to do both):

1. [Add evnta.com to google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url)
2. [ask google to remove issnip2015.org](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals)

and i advise you to perform a host redirect (check what kind of http server you have and google how to do it for your settings...)